# CloudKit cannot get an authentication token

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

So I am trying to connect a CloudKit container to a separate app. I have set "Specify custom containers" to include the container I wish to access and I have included the needed .entitlements
Does anyone know why this error would occur?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally found the documentation for it. The error gets called when:

```
The current user is not authenticated and no user record was available. This might happen if the user is not logged into iCloud.
```

I found out I wasn't logged in on my device. Facepalm.